# How to join with multiple tables in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

The image of the table relation can be found at [image](http://email.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XJ&zTi=1&sdn=email&cdn=compute&tm=50&f=20&su=p284.13.342.ip_&tt=3&bt=3&bts=36&zu=http://imgur.com/).

```
-- Table structure for table `area`
CREATE TABLE `area` (
  `area_id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `area_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`area_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `area` (`area_id`, `area_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Area 1'),
(2, 'Area 2'),
(3, 'Area 3'),
(4, 'Area 4');

-- Table structure for table `fruits`


CREATE TABLE `fruits` (
  `fruit_id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `fruit_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `area_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`fruit_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;



INSERT INTO `fruits` (`fruit_id`, `fruit_name`, `area_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Apple', 1),
(2, 'Orange', 1),
(3, 'Mango', 2),
(4, 'Apricot', 3);


-- Table structure for table `vegetables`
CREATE TABLE `vegetables` (
  `veg_id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `veg_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `area_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`veg_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `vegetables` (`veg_id`, `veg_name`, `area_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Chickpea', 1),
(2, 'Drumstick', 4);
```

If I use the following query I get the output as below

```
SELECT
    `area`.`area_name` AS AreaName
    ,COUNT(*) AS num
FROM
    `area`
    INNER JOIN `fruits`
        ON (`fruits`.`area_id` = `area`.`area_id`)
    GROUP BY `fruits`.area_id   

UNION ALL

SELECT
    `area`.`area_name` AS AreaName
    ,COUNT(*) AS num
FROM
    `area`

    INNER JOIN `vegetables`  
        ON (`vegetables` .`area_id` = `area`.`area_id`)
    GROUP BY `vegetables`.area_id
```

<kbd>AreaName</kbd>    <kbd>num</kbd>
  <kbd>Area 1</kbd>      <kbd>2</kbd>      
  <kbd>Area 2</kbd>      <kbd>1</kbd>      
  <kbd>Area 3</kbd>      <kbd>1</kbd>      
  <kbd>Area 1</kbd>      <kbd>1</kbd>      
  <kbd>Area 4</kbd>      <kbd>1</kbd>

But I want the output to be like:

it should fetch all the areas which are present in vegetables and fruits and if the area is repeating in either fruits or vegetables it should return the total count of area_id by totalling the count of fruits and vegetables.. so the output will be like below

<kbd>AreaName</kbd>    <kbd>num</kbd>
  <kbd>Area 1</kbd>      <kbd>3</kbd>      
  <kbd>Area 2</kbd>      <kbd>1</kbd>      
  <kbd>Area 3</kbd>      <kbd>1</kbd>      
  <kbd>Area 4</kbd>      <kbd>1</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subselect over your query and use `SUM()` to add the counts for same area

```
SELECT t.AreaName ,SUM(t.num) num
FROM ( ....) t
GROUP BY t.AreaName
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c0e4/3)

Comment: @user3477283, don't just go away by saying thanks, if you really appreciate the effort then accept the answer to show your appreciation.

Comment: hai rahul and m khalid junaid, i really appreciate the effort, im really sorry coz i'm new to stack overflow and i didnt knew that...Next time onwards i'l definitely mark it..